# How to check for a key in json object returned by jquery post?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I made a page in php  to get some data from mysql server using jquery post. The post method returns a json object. The json object contains a key named 'warning' if the record requested is already processed one. Else it contains several key value pairs from the requested record. But I am unable to check whether the json object contains a key called 'warning'. What is the problem with my code?

Given below is the form.

```
 <form id="transitentry" name="transitentry" >
      <fieldset>
           <legend>Voucher Details</legend>
           <label for "insert_id">Enter ID:</label><input type="text" id="insert_id" required/><br/>
           <label for "voucher_type">Type of Voucher</label>
           <select name="voucher_type" id="voucher_type" required>
                <option class="green" value="">----Select Voucher Type----</option>
                <option class="green" value="Invoice">Invoice</option>
                <option class="green" value="Hand Receipt">Hand Receipt</option>
                <option class="green" value="Manuscript Voucher">Manuscript Voucher</option>
           </select>
           <br/><br/>

           <label for "invoice_no">Invoice No.:</label><input type="text" id="invoice_no"/><br/>
           <label for "invoice_dt">Invoice/Receipt Date:</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="<?php echo $dateindian; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>" /><input type="hidden" id="stddate" value="<?php echo $dateus; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>"/><br/>
           <label for "item">Item/Description:</label><input class="item" type="text" id="item" size="100" required/><br/>
           <label for "uom">Unit:</label><input type="text" id="uom" required/><br/>

           <label for "qty">Qty:</label><input type="text" id="qty" required/><br/>
           <label for "amount">Amount:</label><input type="text" id="amount" required/><br/>
           <label for "supplier">Supplier</label><input type="text" id="supplier" required/><br/>
           <label for "gst">GST :</label><input class="checkmark" type="checkbox" id="gst" value="Y"/><br/><br/>



           <div align="center"><input id="frmsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"  /></div>
      </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Following jquery code is placed in the page to handle post

```
 jQuery('#insert_id').change(function(){
 var id=jQuery(this).val();

 jQuery.post("scripts/get_imprest_transaction.php",{"insert_id":id},function(data){
      if(data.hasKey("warning")){
           alert(data.warning);
      }else{
           jQuery("#voucher_type").val(data.voucher_type);
           jQuery("#invoice_no").val(data.bill_no);
           jQuery("#datepicker").val(data.dateindian);
           jQuery("#stddate").val(data.date);
           jQuery("#item").val(data.iitem);
           jQuery("#uom").val(data.uom);
           jQuery("#qty").val(data.qty);
           jQuery("#amount").val(data.amount);
           jQuery("#supplier").val(data.supplier);
      }
 });
```

`get_imprest_transaction.php` which sends json object

```
 require_once('../Connections/hari.php');
 $insert_id=$_POST['insert_id'];
 mysql_select_db($database_hari,$hari);
 $sql= "SELECT * from imprest where transact_id=$insert_id";
 $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
      $return_data=array('msg'=>'Invalid ID or Data Not Entered');  
      header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
      echo json_encode($return_data); 
      exit();
 }else {

 //$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if(is_null($row['submission_dt'])){
      $warning='This transaction is already submitted for claim. If you change data , record in the database will differ from the hardcopy submitted to F&A';
      $return_data=array( 'warning'=>$warning);

 }else{
      $dateindian= date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['bill_dt']));
      $item=$row['item'];
      $date=$row['bill_dt'];
      $uom=$row['uom'];
      $qty=$row['qty'];        
      $amount=$row['amount'];
      $bill_no=$row['bill_no'];
      $gst=$row['gst'];
      $voucher_type=$row['voucher_type'];
      $supplier=$row['supplier'];

      $return_data=array('iitem'=>$row['item'],'date'=>$row['bill_dt'], 'uom'=>$row['uom'], 'qty'=>$row['qty'], 'amount'=>$row['amount'], 'bill_no'=>$row['bill_no'], 'dateindian'=>$dateindian, 'gst'=>$row['gst'], 'voucher_type'=>$row['voucher_type'], 'supplier'=>$row['supplier']);  }


      header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
      echo json_encode($return_data); 
      exit();
 }
```

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to further help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an object that represents the parsed JSON, returned by jQuery's `post`.
The problem is that there's no `hasKey` function that's defined as part of this object, so you can't call `data.hasKey`.

Now, assuming `warning` is a first-level property (and not a nested one), you can simply replace:

```
if (data.hasKey('warning'))
```

with:

```
if (data.warning !== undefined)
```